# Cygwin JVM error while trying to launch Nutch Win-7

Tags: cygwin, nutch

I am trying to launch apache-nutch from win, so used cygwin but whenever I run the command

```
bin/crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

it throws the error-

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I already changed the JAVA_HEAP_MAX in bin\nutch with higher value and tried but nothing worked.

Comment: I'm not sure  where the jvm in invoked, but I'm guessing that the heap needs to be bigger. Try 4g or something large like that.

Comment: tried that solution .. naah .. it didn't work

Comment: Well you need more memory... Are you certain your flags are correct and passed in the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I realized that

```
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

does mean that more memory requirement is the trouble as some windows applications were pulling more memory , so I decrease the memory and problem solved.